# Prove matrices multiplied by vectors span a space, and matrices multiplied by vectors are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let A and B be 4 × 4 matrices such that
$$AB=I_4$$
let **$x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5$** be vectors in $\mathbb R^4$ that span $\mathbb R^4$, and let **$y_1, y_2, y_3$** be vectors in $\mathbb R^4$ that are linearly independent. Prove (accurately) that

- the vectors **$Ax_1, Ax_2, Ax_3, Ax_4, Ax_5$** also span $\mathbb R^4$,
- the vectors **$By_1, By_2, By_3$** are also linearly independent

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are clearly invertible, and that's all we are told about them. So what _do_ you know about invertible matrices?

Comment: would it be that Ax = 0 has only the solution x = 0

Comment: @EmanWong That is indeed one property that invertible matrices have.  Have you tried anything so far?  Do you understand the definitions involved, i.e. what it means for vectors to "span $\Bbb R^4$" and what it means for vectors to be linearly independent?  Have you tried using these definitions to start a proof?  If so, then where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I'm just not sure how to even go about proving both of these statements. I'm not sure what condition am i trying to show in order to show that the vectors span $ R^4$ or are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's important to note that if $AB = I_4$, then (since $A,B$ are square matrices) we have $B = A^{-1}$ and $A = B^{-1}$, which is to say that 
$$
AB = BA = I_4.
$$
For more on that, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3852/81360).

Let's go through the first problem.  We are trying to show that $Ax_1,\dots,Ax_5$ span $\Bbb R^4$.  By definition, that means the following:

> For any vector $b \in \Bbb R^4$, there exist coefficients $c_i$ such that $c_1 Ax_1 + \cdots + c_5 Ax_5 = b$.

With that in mind, we can construct the proof as follows.  Begin with a vector $b \in \Bbb R^4$; our goal will be to show that satisfactory coefficients $c_i$ exist.  Before writing a formal proof, it is useful to note that
$$
c_1 Ax_1 + \cdots + c_5 Ax_5 = b \iff\\
A[c_1 x_1 + \cdots + c_5 x_5] = b \iff\\
c_1 x_1 + \cdots + c_5 x_5 = A^{-1}b
$$

That is, we have come to the following insight: if there exist coefficients such that $c_1 x_1 + \cdots + c_5 x_5 = A^{-1}b$, then these same coefficients will satisfy $c_1 Ax_1 + \cdots + c_5 Ax_5 = b$, which is ultimately what we want.

Thus, one proof would be as follows: argue that there exist coefficients $c_i$ for which $c_1 x_1 + \cdots + c_5 x_5 = A^{-1}b$ (how do we know that this is true?). Then, present the series of equations above to conclude that these coefficients also satisfy $c_1 Ax_1 + \cdots + c_5 Ax_5 = b$.  Because $b$ was an arbitrary vector in $\Bbb R^4$, this is exactly the conclusion we want: the vectors $Ax_1,\dots,Ax_5$ span $\Bbb R^4$.

---

If we want to avoid the result that I refer to in the beginning (desirable in the infinite-dimensional case for instance), then the problem is a bit trickier but the idea is essentially the same.

First, select $c_1,\dots,c_5$ such that
$$
c_1x_1 + \cdots + c_5 x_5 = Bb.
$$
Now, multiply both sides of the equation (from the left) by $A$ to find that
$$
A(c_1x_1 + \cdots + c_5 x_5) = A(Bb) \implies\\
c_1(Ax_1) + \cdots + c_5(Ax_5) = (AB)b \implies\\
c_1(Ax_1) + \cdots + c_5(Ax_5) = b
$$
so that once again, we can conclude that $Ax_1,\dots,Ax_5$ spans $\Bbb R^4$.